# Always select the same images with Random Seed

Tags: python

I'm a beginner, so please be nice :)

i would like to set a random seed for my data set.
the data set contains the different values of individual images, which assess the quality of the image. You can see this clearly in the list. The last column "Votes" has already been summarized by averaging.

Now my question is where and how I put the random seed?
When splitting the data? when training the model? or right at the beginning?

In my case, the Random Seed should ensure that the same image / video sequences are always used for training and evaluation. That means putting some value at the beginning won't do me much good, will it?

[image]

Comment: Could you please format your question with the code inside the question body? Remember, if you make it harder for people to help you, you are less likely to get help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want experimentation reproducibility, I recommend you to start the notebook with this cell:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

seed = 42
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
```